# Redis lpop function returning true rather than original value

Tags: javascript, redis

I have a list of unique strings which i ll need to pop based on user, so I am using lpop of redis to do that, the problem is when trying to lpop from hash value true is being returned and the item is being removed but its not beign returned as a value(original value) but as true.

List is not empty and redis connection is working.

"redis": "^2.8.0",

```
export async function LPOP(hashKey, initialSource, fromWhere) {
    try {
        let redis = initialSource[fromWhere];

        const result = await redis.lpop([hashKey]);

        if (result) {
            return JSON.parse(result);
        }

        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node Redis 2.8.0 is very, very old. It didn't support Promises—which you are using. This is probably the heart of your error. I would suggest either upgrading to the latest version:

```js
const result = await client.lPop(key)
```

Or using the older syntax:

```js
client.lpop(key, function(err, result) {
  // do something with the result
})
```